# Cert unable to be installed in cpanel

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

I don't know much about this topic, but have a site (shared hosting) and want ssl for it. Got a certificate from letsencrypt (for both www and plain mydomain.com), they verified it successfully, so I put the cert and private key into the ssl config part of cpanel. Cpanel marked the inputs valid but then gave me the following error

```
The certificate could not be installed on the domain “mydomain.com”.

error Certificate verification failed!
Certificate verification failed:
unable to load certificate
140495454865312:error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode:pem_lib.c:812:
```

I have no idea what this means. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you generate your cert request?

Comment: Got it to work, thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by making sure every line was exactly 64 characters long